# Spark Logistic regression and precisionByThreshold

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

```
def precisionByThreshold(): RDD[(Double, Double)]
```

I understand that this above method returns the (threshold, precision) curve. Let us say one of the entries is (0.85, X) does that mean the precision calculated when model was classifying in the following manner (assuming we have only 2 classes): if the predicted score is < 0.85 class 1 else class 2. We then use that result to calculate precision. I just want to make sure that my understanding is correct.